# PHP associate array to HTML table

Tags: php, arrays

We have an HTML page which uses a `fgetcsv` function to produce an array like the following...

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [KEY1] => Data1 [KEY2] => Data2 [KEY3] => Data3 )
    [1] => Array ( [KEY1] => Data1 [KEY2] => Data2 [KEY3] => Data3 )
    [2] => Array ( [KEY1] => Data1 [KEY2] => Data2 [KEY3] => Data3 )
)
```

We would like to use this array to populate cells in an HTML table.

Row 1, draws from the first row:  contents of Cell 1 = Data1, contents of Cell 2 = Data2, contents of Cell 3 = Data3.

Row 2, draws from the second row:  contents of Cell 1 = Data1, contents of Cell 2 = Data2, contents of Cell 3 = Data3.

And so on.
We cannot get the syntax of the for each statement correct, nor the references from the individual table cells to the array values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: fgetcsv doesn't produce an array with string keys as far as I know.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($arrayName as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[KEY1]."</td><td>".$row[KEY2]."</td><td>".$row[KEY3]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This should work for the case you specified.

Comment: Thank you both!  We have implemented Drews suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

Your Array example:

```
 Array ( 
         [0] => Array 
                ( [KEY1] => Data1,
                  [KEY2] => Data2,
                  [KEY3] => Data3 ),
          [1] => Array 
                ( [KEY1] => Data1,
                   [KEY2] => Data2,
                    [KEY3] => Data3 ),
           [2] => Array 
                ( [KEY1] => Data1,
                  [KEY2] => Data2,
                  [KEY3] => Data3 )
        );
```

My Example Of your Array

```
data = Array (
             0 => Array(
                 'first_name' => 'Justin',
                 'last_name' => 'Hughes',
                 'email' => 'Justin@gmail.com' ),
              1 => Array(
                  'first_name' => 'Joe',
                  'last_name' => 'Dirt',
                  'email' => 'Joe@dirt.com' ),
               2 => Array(
                  'first_name' => 'Luke',
                  'last_name' => 'Skywalker',
                  'email' => 'Luke@TheForce.com' )
            );
        echo '<table>';
        foreach($data as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($row as $value){
                echo "<td>$value</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Hope this helps.